# Exclude dataset from a query

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have 2 tables

- `EXAM` (`StudentID, SubjectID, SchoolYear, Period, Mark`) and
- `CANCELED`_EXAM (`StudentID, SubjectID, SchoolYear, Period`).

Primary key for both tables are (`StudentID, SubjectID, SchoolYear, Period`).

When a student wants to take an exam,  then we write one row in `EXAM` table.
But if a student passed an exam and is not satisfied, then he wants to cancel the exam and we need to write one row in table `CANCELED_EXAM`.

My question is: How to select just non-canceled exams from table `EXAM`.

Comment: I'd consider having them as one table, with a flag IsCancelled

Comment: I didn't posted here that table CANCELED_EXAM has columns ReasonForCancel and CancelDate. Putting these two columns into EXAM   would destroy normalization.

Comment: Not true, having two null fields will not kill normalization, because if they were filled in then you wouldn't need the flag field, so thus they would eventually serve that self-same purpose. I understand your reason for wanting to "normalize" it to that extent, but that's just pushing normalization to an unhealthy extreme. Even Codd would agree to that, I'm sure. It would also reduce almost all of the complexity of this request (which I can tell is going to arise many times in the logic of this app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is standard SQL

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   EXAM E
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM
          CANCELED_EXAM CE
       WHERE
          E.StudentID = CE.StudentID AND
          E.SubjectID = CE.SubjectID AND
          E.SchoolYear = CE.SchoolYear AND
          E.Period = CE.Period )
```

Comment: That is right solution, I didn't know for this.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to perform a LEFT JOIN

Standard SQL

```
SELECT
    E.*
FROM
    EXAM E LEFT JOIN
    CANCELLED_EXAM CE
    ON E.StudentID = CE.StudentID AND
       E.SubjectID = CE.SubjectID AND
       E.SchoolYear = CE.SchoolYear AND
       E.Period = CE.Period
WHERE
    CE.StudentID IS NULL;
```

MySQL Dialect

```
SELECT
    E.*
FROM
    EXAM E LEFT JOIN
    CANCELLED_EXAM CE
    USING (StudentID, SubjectID, SchoolYear, Period)
WHERE
    CE.StudentID IS NULL;
```

Comment: You are right, I found this on MySQL doc site:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html